# Elastic search - Error when creating node / index in java

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm trying to get proof of concept Java code working. The first thing I'm trying to do is index some txt documents on my HD. However I don't even get that far before running into exceptions when trying to create a Node.

The following code all produces the exception below:

**Code**

```
Node node = nodeBuilder().node();
Client client = node.client();
```

**My main Questions is** :

WHere can I get the BoundaryScanner class that seems to be missing? I'll provide my maven **pom.xml** below the exception. The lucene-fast-vector-highlighter package seems to be the lastest version [3.0.3](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.lucene/lucene-fast-vector-highlighter).

Any help much appreciated.

**Exception**

```
    07-Jun-2012 12:44:00 org.elasticsearch.node
INFO: [Allatou] {0.19.4}[2648]: initializing ...
07-Jun-2012 12:44:00 org.elasticsearch.plugins
INFO: [Allatou] loaded [], sites []
Exception in thread "main" org.elasticsearch.common.collect.ComputationException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/search/vectorhighlight/BoundaryScanner
    at org.elasticsearch.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingMapAdapter.get(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:400)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.internal.FailableCache.get(FailableCache.java:49)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ConstructorInjectorStore.get(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:50)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ConstructorBindingImpl.initialize(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:50)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorImpl.initializeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:370)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.BindingProcessor$1$1.run(BindingProcessor.java:148)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.BindingProcessor.initializeBindings(BindingProcessor.java:204)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorBuilder.initializeStatically(InjectorBuilder.java:119)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorBuilder.build(InjectorBuilder.java:102)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:93)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:70)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ModulesBuilder.createInjector(ModulesBuilder.java:59)
    at org.elasticsearch.node.internal.InternalNode.<init>(InternalNode.java:149)
    at org.elasticsearch.node.NodeBuilder.build(NodeBuilder.java:159)
    at org.elasticsearch.node.NodeBuilder.node(NodeBuilder.java:166)
    at ie.openmobile.elasticsearch.Main.main(Main.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/search/vectorhighlight/BoundaryScanner
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forConstructorOf(InjectionPoint.java:177)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ConstructorInjectorStore.createConstructor(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:59)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ConstructorInjectorStore.access$000(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:29)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ConstructorInjectorStore$1.create(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:37)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ConstructorInjectorStore$1.create(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:33)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.internal.FailableCache$1.apply(FailableCache.java:38)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingValueReference.compute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:358)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingSegment.compute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:184)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingSegment.getOrCompute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:153)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap.getOrCompute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:69)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingMapAdapter.get(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:396)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.lucene.search.vectorhighlight.BoundaryScanner
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 29 more
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

      <groupId>com.examplegroup</groupId>
      <artifactId>artifacename</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <packaging>jar</packaging>

      <name>elasticsearch</name>
      <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>


      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12</version>
            <configuration>
              <systemPropertyVariables>
                <user.region>uk</user.region>
              </systemPropertyVariables>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>


      <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
      </properties>

         <repositories> 


         <repository> 
         <!-- elasticsearch hosted here -->
           <id>sonatype-releases</id> 
           <name>Sonatype Releases Repository</name> 
           <url>http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/</url> 
         </repository> 

       </repositories> 


      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.1</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
        <!-- jsoup HTML parser library @ http://jsoup.org/ -->
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.3</version>
        </dependency>

          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
            <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
          </dependency>           

          <dependency>                  
            <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
            <artifactId>lucene-analyzers</artifactId>   
            <version>3.6.0</version>                            
          </dependency>                                               

          <dependency>                                                      
            <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>                                    
            <artifactId>lucene-snowball</artifactId>                                          
            <version>3.0.3</version>                                                                    
          </dependency>                                                                                         

          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
            <artifactId>lucene-fast-vector-highlighter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3</version>
          </dependency>

          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
            <artifactId>lucene-highlighter</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
          </dependency>

          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
            <artifactId>lucene-queries</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
          </dependency>


          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>0.19.4</version>
          </dependency>
      </dependencies>



    </project>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a good idea to mix different versions of Lucene components in the same project. You should be using 3.6.0 for everything. There were some changes in the recent versions, so you will need to replaces/remove some artifacts. For example, the Snowball analyzer is now in lucene-analyzers, so you shouldn't need lucene-snowball artifact, and lucene-fast-vector-highlighter is now in lucene-highlighter:

```
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0</version>
      </dependency>           

      <dependency>                  
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-analyzers</artifactId>   
        <version>3.6.0</version>                            
      </dependency>                                               

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-highlighter</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-queries</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0</version>
      </dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks imotov. I was just writing out the same thing when you posted your answer. Specifically the java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError referred to the lucene-highlighter package which in the question was 2.4.0. When it (and everything else) is updated to 3.6.0 it runs fine. Thanks for the time and effort. Oh and thanks for the extra info about new artifacts.